# why i can't reach my database?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

This my dbconnect.class.php

```
<?php 

class Connect
{
    //public $error;
    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1");
        $db = mysql_select_db("tarih",$link);
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

$connect = new Connect();
$connect = $connect->db;
?>
```

And this is main php file (header.class.php)

```
<?php
require_once ('dbconnect.class.php');
class Header extends Connect
{ 
    public $headers = array();
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        /* 
        * Bu sınıf sayfaların header bilgilerini işler. 
        */  
    } 

    public function sayfaHeader($sayfa = true) 
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'"; 
        $query = mysql_query($sql,$connect) or mysql_error(); 
        echo $sql;
    } 


} 

$header = new Header();
echo $header->sayfaHeader();
?>
```

But when i run this code I see this error:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\header.class.php on line 16

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you remember to plug in the network cable? *runs*

Comment: Take a look at the output of `mysql_error()` after the connect fails.

Comment: Look to code.. I can't connect mysql. According to I can't see print mysql_error()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$connect` variable is a parent class. You need to point to the `$link` variable it contains.

Change:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql, $connect) or mysql_error();
```

to

```
$query = mysql_query($sql,$link) or mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$connect` is not in the scope of the class. Either you leave it out and `mysql_query` chooses the last available resource. Or you can pass-through your `$connect` variable into the class:

```
require_once ('dbconnect.class.php');
class Header extends Connect
{ 
    public $headers = array();
    protected $database;

    public function __construct($database) 
    { 
        /* 
        * Bu sınıf sayfaların header bilgilerini işler. 
        */  
        $this->database = $database;
    } 

    public function sayfaHeader($sayfa = true) 
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'"; 
        $query = mysql_query($sql,$this->database) or mysql_error(); 
        echo $sql;
    } 
} 

$header = new Header($connect); // here you pass-through your resource
echo $header->sayfaHeader();
```

---

I also want to mention that you should look into [Design Patterns](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/), because it's just some pseudo OOP which you are creating.

Comment: this isn't solve my problem.. I can see only: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\header.class.php on line 19

Comment: Did you try it without the second parameter?

Comment: what is the second parameter?

Comment: In this case it is `$this->database` just try to leave it out. According to the manual it means this: `link_identifier -- The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed.`